# Converting nginx uuid from hex to Base64: how is byte-order involved?

Tags: ruby, nginx, binary, endianness, nibble

Nginx can be configured to generate a [uuid suitable for client identification](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_userid_module.html). Upon receiving a request from a new client, it appends a uuid in two forms before forwarding the request upstream to the origin server(s):

- cookie with uuid in Base64 (e.g. `CgIGR1ZfUkeEXQ2YAwMZAg==`)
- header with uuid in hexadecimal (e.g. `4706020A47525F56980D5D8402190303`)

I want to convert a hexadecimal representation to the Base64 equivalent. I have a working solution in Ruby, but I don't fully grasp the underlying mechanics, especially the switching of byte-orders:

```
hex_str = "4706020A47525F56980D5D8402190303"
```

Treating `hex_str` as a sequence of *high-nibble* (most significant 4 bits first) binary data, produce the (ASCII-encoded) string representation:

```
binary_seq = [hex_str].pack("H*")

# 47 (71 decimal) -> "G"
# 06  (6 decimal) -> "\x06" (non-printable)
# 02  (2 decimal) -> "\x02" (non-printable)
# 0A (10 decimal) -> "\n"
# ...

#=> "G\x06\x02\nGR_V\x98\r]\x84\x02\x19\x03\x03"
```

Map `binary_seq` to an array of 32-bit *little-endian* unsigned integers. Each 4 characters (4 bytes = 32 bits) maps to an integer:

```
data = binary_seq.unpack("VVVV")

# "G\x06\x02\n"      ->  167904839 (?)
# "GR_V"             -> 1449087559 (?)
# "\x98\r]\x84"      -> 2220690840 (?)
# "\x02\x19\x03\x03" ->   50534658 (?)

#=> [167904839, 1449087559, 2220690840, 50534658]
```

Treating `data` as an array of 32-bit *big-endian* unsigned integers, produce the (ASCII-encoded) string representation:

```
network_seq = data.pack("NNNN")

#  167904839 -> "\n\x02\x06G"      (?)
# 1449087559 -> "V_RG"             (?)
# 2220690840 -> "\x84]\r\x98"      (?)
#   50534658 -> "\x03\x03\x19\x02" (?)

#=> "\n\x02\x06GV_RG\x84]\r\x98\x03\x03\x19\x02"
```

Encode `network_seq` in Base64 string:

```
Base64.encode64(network_seq).strip

#=> "CgIGR1ZfUkeEXQ2YAwMZAg=="
```

My rough understanding is that big-endian is the standard byte-order for network communications, while little-endian is more common on host machines. Why nginx provides two forms that require switching byte order to convert I'm not sure.

I also don't understand how the `.unpack("VVVV")` and `.pack("NNNN")` steps work. I can see that `G\x06\x02\n` becomes `\n\x02\x06G`, but I don't understand the steps that get there. For example, focusing on the first 8 digits of `hex_str`, why do `.pack(H*)` and `.unpack("VVVV")` produce:

```
"4706020A" -> "G\x06\x02\n" -> 167904839
```

whereas converting directly to base-10 produces:

```
"4706020A".to_i(16) -> 1191576074
```

? The fact that I'm asking this shows I need clarification on what exactly is going on in all these conversions :)

Comment: Have you looked at the WebServerUid gem? https://github.com/swiftype/web_server_uid I don't know if it solves your problem, but the README does mention that the cookie is "a Base64-encoded, endianness-reversed version of the exact same data" in the hex string. The source code is extremely well-commented: https://github.com/swiftype/web_server_uid/blob/master/lib/web_server_uid.rb

Comment: @jordan yes, actually that's where I started to see how it could be done. It is pretty well commented, but I guess I need to break it down more to see exactly where the gaps in my knowledge are.